# put order by in right place mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-select-db

i have query like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.name, 'total') AS `product name`, 
       SUM(omd.quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
       SUM(omd.quantity) / any_value(total_sum) * 100 AS `Qty(%)`, 
       COUNT(om.id) AS `COunt Order`,
       COUNT(om.id) / any_value(total_count) * 100 AS `Count Order(%)`
FROM order_match om
INNER JOIN order_match_detail omd
ON om.id = omd.order_match_id
INNER JOIN product p
on omd.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN (select SUM(omd1.quantity) total_sum,
        count(om1.id) total_count
    FROM order_match om1
    INNER JOIN 
    order_match_detail omd1
    ON om1.id = omd1.order_match_id
    where om1.order_status_id in 
    (4, 5, 6, 8)) totals
    where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
    group by p.name with rollup;
```

and after running that query the result was this (this is just dummy)

```
+--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Product Name | Qty(kg) | Qty(%) | COunt Order | Count Order (%) |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Product A    |      20 |     20 |          10 |              10 |
| Product B    |      30 |     30 |          10 |              10 |
| Product C    |      45 |     45 |          30 |              30 |
| Product D    |       5 |      5 |          50 |              50 |
| TOtal        |     100 |    100 |         100 |             100 |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

i want to put `order by` and order based on the Qty(kg)

the expected result was this

```
 +--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Product Name | Qty(kg) | Qty(%) | COunt Order | Count Order (%) |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Product C    |      45 |     45 |          30 |              30 |
| Product B    |      30 |     30 |          10 |              10 |
| Product A    |      20 |     20 |          10 |              10 |
| Product D    |       5 |      5 |          50 |              50 |
| TOtal        |     100 |    100 |         100 |             100 |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

so this is my query after i put order by

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.name, 'total') AS `product name`, 
       SUM(omd.quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
       SUM(omd.quantity) / any_value(total_sum) * 100 AS `Qty(%)`, 
       COUNT(om.id) AS `COunt Order`,
       COUNT(om.id) / any_value(total_count) * 100 AS `Count Order(%)`
FROM order_match om
INNER JOIN order_match_detail omd
ON om.id = omd.order_match_id
INNER JOIN product p
on omd.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN (select SUM(omd1.quantity) total_sum,
        count(om1.id) total_count
    FROM order_match om1
    INNER JOIN 
    order_match_detail omd1
    ON om1.id = omd1.order_match_id
    where om1.order_status_id in 
    (4, 5, 6, 8)) totals
    where om.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
    group by p.name with rollup
    order by omd.quantity DESC;
```

but after i run it, the notification just like this

```
Error COde :1221. Incorrect usage of CUBE/R0LLUP and ORDER BY
```

so which part i should edit or add so it can be ordered by what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add ORDER BY after GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP. Convert your query to subquery (or CTE if its version is 8+) and sort its output in outer query storing rollup result last:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT COALESCE(p.name, 'Total') AS `product name`, 
              SUM(omd.quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
              SUM(omd.quantity) / ANY_VALUE(total_sum) * 100 AS `Qty(%)`, 
              COUNT(om.id) AS `Count Order`,
              COUNT(om.id) / ANY_VALUE(total_count) * 100 AS `Count Order(%)`
       FROM order_match AS om
       INNER JOIN order_match_detail AS omd ON om.id = omd.order_match_id
       INNER JOIN product AS p ON omd.product_id = p.id
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(omd1.quantity) AS total_sum,
                           COUNT(om1.id) AS total_count
                    FROM order_match AS om1
                    INNER JOIN order_match_detail AS omd1 ON om1.id = omd1.order_match_id
                    WHERE om1.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6, 8)
                  ) AS totals
       WHERE om.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6, 8)
       GROUP BY p.name WITH ROLLUP 
     ) AS subquery
ORDER BY `product name`='Total', `Qty(kg)` DESC;
```